# Is it possible to grab the NUMBER that was concatenated to a string? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

I'm using cookies and I am setting them like this:

```
document.cookie ="cookievalue1="+cookievalue1; 
document.cookie ="cookievalue2="+cookievalue2;
document.cookie ="cookievalue3="+cookievalue3;
```

Then I put it all in an array called cookie array:

```
var allcookies = document.cookie;
cookiearray = allcookies.split(';');
```

If I print out the array, I get something like: cookievalue1= 23 or cookievalue2= 42.

But is there any way I could JUST get the value after the string (23 or 42 only)
rather than the string and the number?

I tried deleting the "cookievalue=" part, but that makes it so I can't store cookies. I'm using forms and I just want the numbers inputted so I can use them and add/subtract them on another page. Right now, I can't add or subtract anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
allcookies.split(';').map(c => c.split('=')[1]);
```

It'd give you back the cookie value as a string. If you are certain they are all numbers you can do:

```
allcookies.split(';').map(c => +c.split('=')[1]);
```

This gives you back the cookie values as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

this function should work

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var cookievalue3 = getCookie("cookievalue3");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split it again

```
var allcookies = "cookievalue1=23;cookeivalue2=22";

cookiearray.forEach(function(value) { 
    pair = value.split('='); 
    console.log(pair[1])
});
```